# Is there a way to determine whether the current / last visual block selection is non-rectangular?

Tags: visual-mode, visual-block

One can create non-rectangular Visual-Block selections using `C-v$` on files with lines of non-equal length.

Is it possible to programmatically determine whether the last Visual Block selection was non-rectangular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little crude but this works...

```
func! IsDollarBlock()
    let l:mode = char2nr(visualmode(""))
    if l:mode != 22
        echom char2nr(l:mode) . " is not block mode"
        return 0
    endif

    sil norm! gv"aygv$"by
    return @a == @b
endfunc
```

You can test with...

```
:echo IsDollarBlock()
```

(Assuming visual selection was not active)...first this checks whether the last visual selection was even block mode. If not it returns 0 (false). Otherwise it re-selects the visual selection and yanks into register "a", re-selects it again, issues `$` and yanks into register "b". Then it compares the two registers and returns the comparison result (0/false or 1/true).

If you wanted to preserve the visual selection you could issue `<Esc>` or equivalent at the beginning of the function then put `norm! gv` as last command of the function.

Comment: Alternate algorithm: if the lengths of the lines differ at all, it must be non-rectangular. Something like `len(uniq(sort(map(lines, strlen)))) != 1`

Comment: Hey DBK. My first thought was to use line lengths but you can make a non-rectangular selection without `$` and the question is specifically about creating selections with `$`.